# Tensorflow lite combine models?

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow-datasets

Is there any way to combine 2 tensorflow lite models?. I am trying to make an android traffic app that detects vehicles pedestrians and traffic signs.
One of the models can detect vehicles and pedestrians, the other can detect different traffic signs.
OR
Is there a way to make a button in the UI that can switch between the two models?